# Definition of Exact functors

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories, exact-sequence

As we know by definition, a functor for example $T\colon R\textrm{-}\mathsf{Mod}\to\mathsf{Ab}$ (from the category of $R$-modules to the category of abelian groups) is "exact" precisely when for any short exact sequence:
$$0 \to A \to  B\to  C\to 0$$
the sequence
$$0\to  T(A) \to  T(B) \to  T(C) \to  0$$
is also exact.

My question is: Is this equivalent to the condition where these sequences do not begin with zero? In other words can we say $T\colon R\textrm{-}\mathsf{Mod}\to\mathsf{Ab}$ is exact precisely when for any exact sequence:
$$A \to B \to C,$$
the sequence
$$T(A) \to T(B) \to T(C)$$
is also exact?

Obviously, the latter implies the exactness definition, but I am not yet convinced about the other direction.

Comment: Yes. Break your latter sequence into a few short exact sequences involving kernels and cokernels.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157783/equivalent-definition-of-exactness-of-functor) answer.

Comment: @Girish: Thanks for catching that. This question should be closed as a duplicate (not that you did anything wrong Sean, we just want to keep related discussions all in one place).

Comment: Thank you all,,,in fact it was my first experience to post a question here; apparently a similar question has already been asked and thanks for directing me to that question.