# Functor preserving long exact sequences

Tags: homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, exact-sequence

Let $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ be abelian categories.

An exact functor $F:\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{D}$ preserves exactness of short exact sequences:

$$0\to A\to B\to C\to 0$$
goes to 
$$0\to F(A)\to F(B)\to F(C)\to 0$$

I don't believe that this implies long exact sequences are sent to long exact sequences.

0) Am I wrong? If not:

1) What tools do we have to measure the failure of $F$ in taking a long exact to a long exact?

2) Is there a name for a functor that takes long exact sequences to long exact sequences?

Comment: Sorry if this question is dumb, I think maybe I am wrong at step 0

Comment: 0) It's wrong: if $F$ preserves short exact sequences, then it preserves kernels and images so it preserves exactness at any node of a long exact sequence.

Comment: @Berci Is it true that it preserves limits and colimits or something like that?

Comment: It preserves kernels and binary products hence finite limits; and it preserves cokernels and binary coproducts hence finite colimits

Comment: Possible duplicate of [showing exact functors preserve exact sequences (abelian categories, additive functors, and kernels)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/803578/showing-exact-functors-preserve-exact-sequences-abelian-categories-additive-fu)