# Atiyah & MacDonald Proposition 2.19 ii) -> i)

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

The full proposition (Atiyah & MacDonald Proposition 2.19) is the following: (sorry for the oversized image, not sure how to make it smaller)
[image: Text]
I'm trying to show ii) implies i). As per the hint, we start with a long exact sequence
$$\cdots\to A\overset{f}{\to}B\overset{g}{\to} C\to\cdots\qquad (1)$$ and to show $N$ is flat, we need to show that
$$\cdots\to A\otimes N\overset{f\otimes 1}{\to}B\otimes N\overset{g\otimes 1}{\to} C\otimes N\to\cdots\qquad (2)$$ is also exact. If we can show exactness at $B\otimes N$, we are basically done. From the first sequence we obtain a short exact sequence
$$0\to f(A)\overset{j}{\to} B\overset{g}{\to} g(B)\to 0\qquad (3)$$ where $j$ is the inclusion map. From ii) we have that $$0\to f(A)\otimes N\overset{j\otimes 1}{\to} B\otimes N\overset{g\otimes 1}{\to} g(B)\otimes N\to 0\qquad (4)$$ which is also exact, so we have $\text{Im}(j\otimes 1)=\text{Ker}(g\otimes 1)$. Now, recall to show (2) is exact at $B\otimes N$ we need to show $\text{Im}(f\otimes 1)=\text{Ker}(g\otimes 1)$. So, we have
$$\begin{align*}
\text{Ker}(g\otimes 1)&=\text{Im}(j\otimes 1)\\
&=(j\otimes 1)(f(A)\otimes N)\\
&=(j\circ f(A))\otimes N\\
&= f(A)\otimes 1(N)\\
&=(f\otimes 1)(A\otimes N)\\
&=\text{Im}(f\otimes 1)
\end{align*}$$
which shows (2) is exact at $B\otimes N$ and we are done. Can someone let me know if this is correct, and if it isn't whether or not I'm on the right track? I've seen some other solutions on this website that seem more complicated so I'm not sure if I am missing something. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [showing exact functors preserve exact sequences (abelian categories, additive functors, and kernels)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/803578/showing-exact-functors-preserve-exact-sequences-abelian-categories-additive-fu)

Comment: @azif00 I don't fully understand - I don't have a strong background with category theory

Comment: We don’t need any background in category theory. Just read the proof but with $F = (\_) \otimes N$. If you have any problems, let me know :)

Comment: @azif00 Ah yes, going through it now it mostly makes sense - thank you. I was wondering through if you could further explain the points towards the end that says "where ∗ holds since (′)→(Im) is epi and ⊛ holds since (Im)→(′′) is mono." I understand this point thinking of everything as regular module homomorphisms but I'm curious how it works out in a more general category.

Comment: Regarding the image size, there are several sizes stored by imgur, so sometimes a smaller size can be useful by adding a letter m to the end of the URL string (before the .png).  But I thought that made it too small to read here.  In any case a better approach is to format the proposition statement in $\LaTeX$.